# PGF of a Poisson-binomial

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

Let $N$ being a Poisson-binomial random integer with success rates $r_1,\dots,r_K \in [0,1]$.
Since $N$ can be written as the sum of $K$ independent Bernoulli integers $N_i$ (each one with success rate $r_i$), i.e.
\begin{equation*}
N=\sum_{i=1}^K N_i
\end{equation*}
it follows that the Probability Generating Function (PGF) of $N$ is factorized as
\begin{equation*}
G_{N}(s)=\prod_{i=1}^K G_{N_i}(s)=\prod_{i=1}^K(1-r_i+r_is)
\end{equation*}
where it was noted that the PGF of $N_i$ is $G_{N_i}(s)=(1-r_i+r_is)$. Now, I would like to obtain the same result by employing the definition of PGF, that is
\begin{equation*}
G_N(s)\triangleq \sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{N}(n)\,s^n 
\end{equation*}
where $p_N(n)$ is the probability distribution of $N$, and can be written in the following form
\begin{equation*}
p_N(n)=\sum_{i_{1:n}\in P_{n,K}^{>}} \prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq i_{1:n}}}^{K}(1-r_i)\,\prod_{j=1}^n r_{i_j} \qquad 0\leq n \leq K
\end{equation*}
where are introduced the following symbols:

- $i_{1:n}=(i_1,i_2,\dots, i_j, \dots, i_n)$ is a string of $n$ indexes $i_j$
- $P_{n,K}^{>}$ is a matrix composed by all strictly increasing ($i_{j+1}>i_j$) strings $i_{1:n}$ where each index $i_j$ can get value in $\{1,2,\dots,K\}$. Each row of $P_{n,K}^{>}$ is a string $i_{1:n}$
- $\sum_{i_{1:n}\in P_{n,K}^{>}}$ means that the summation is taken over the rows of $P_{n,K}^{>}$
- $\prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq i_{1:n}}}^{K}$ means that the product is taken over all indexes $i\in\{1,2,\dots,K\}$ that are not used in $i_{1:n}$

In particular, $p_n(0)=\prod_{i=1}^K (1-r_i)$.

**Example**

Let $n=2$ and $K=3$, then
\begin{equation*}
P_{2,3}^{>}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
2 & 3
\end{array}\right] \qquad \rightarrow \qquad
p_N(2)=(1-r_3)\,r_1\,r_2+(1-r_2)\,r_1\,r_3+(1-r_1)\,r_2\,r_3
\end{equation*}

**Question**

I want to prove the following identity
\begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}
\sum_{n=0}^K \left(\sum_{i_{1:n}\in P_{n,K}^{>}} \prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq i_{1:n}}}^{K}(1-r_i)\,\prod_{j=1}^n r_{i_j}\right)\,s^n=\prod_{i=1}^K (1-r_i+r_i s)
\end{equation}

**A simplified problem**

If the $K$ success rates $r_1,\dots,r_K$ are equal to some $r$, then the previous Poisson-binomial model reduces to the more conventional binomial model, that is
\begin{equation*}
G_N(s)=(1-r_i+r_i s)^K
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
p_N(n)=\binom{K}{n}\,(1-r)^{K-n}\,r^n
\end{equation*}
in this case my problem reduces to prove the identity
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^K \left(\binom{K}{n}\,(1-r)^{K-n}\,r^n\right) s^n = (1-r+r s)^K
\end{equation*}
which can be easily handled with the binomial theorem. From this point of view, I'm wondering if it exists a sort of generalized binomial theorem that can be used to prove the identity $(\star)$.